# How to show a fragment inside a specific Fragment Container in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

Whenever I want to change fragment depending on the item selected I use:
`getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).commit();`

But now I want to make it so that I can simply show the different fragments instead of creating new ones every time I re-select them, so I found `.show` instead of `.replace`, but the problem with `.show` is that I can not declare where I want that fragment to be shown... or perhaps I'm maybe doing it wrong:

`getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().show(fragment).commit();`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use **show/hide** method, you need to add a fragment before this, as you can see the container is available here. I just showed an example of how to show or hide one fragment. If you have a lot of fragments you can for example save the list and then hide others in the loop. If interested, I added from below.

```
 public void showFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        if (fragment.isAdded()) {
            fragmentTransaction.show(fragment);
        } else {
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, fragment);
        }
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }


public void hideFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    if (fragment.isAdded()) {
        fragmentTransaction.hide(fragment);
    }
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

*If there are many fragments*

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    HashMap<String, Fragment> fragments = new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    /*
     * call this method when you want to add a new fragment
     * Example: addFragment(new A(), "TAG_A")
     * */
    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String fragmentTag) {
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        /*Before add fragment we hide others*/
        for (String fTag : fragments.keySet()) {
            Fragment fragmentInStack = fragments.get(fTag);
            if (fragmentInStack.isAdded() && !fragmentInStack.isHidden()) {
                fragmentTransaction.hide(fragmentInStack);
            }
        }

        if (!fragment.isAdded()) {
            fragments.put(fragmentTag, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, fragment, fragmentTag);
        } else {
            fragmentTransaction.show(fragment);
        }

        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

    /*
     * call this method when you want to show fragment which are on the list
     * Example: We have current fragment C and you want to show fragment A, that to call showFragment("TAG_A")
     * */
    public void showFragment(String fragmentTag) {
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        /*hide others fragment besides the one we need to show*/
        for (String fTag : fragments.keySet()) {
            Fragment fragmentInStack = fragments.get(fTag);
            if (!fTag.equals(fragmentTag) && fragmentInStack.isAdded()) {
                fragmentTransaction.hide(fragmentInStack);
            }
        }

        Fragment fragment = fragments.get(fragmentTag);
        if (fragment != null && fragment.isAdded()) {
            fragmentTransaction.show(fragment);
        }
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```